# Spatialite: no such function st_geomfromtext

Tags: spatialite

I am using the latest Spatialite and encountered this error "no such function st_geomfromtext" while running my query. It might be a library not running. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Are you using SpatiaLite-GUI or are you using SpatiaLite as a library? What is your environment (development language, operating system, ...)? `st_geomfromtext` is not available on SpatiaLite 2.3.0 (https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.0/spatialite-sql-2.3.0.html) but it is available from SpatiaLite 3.0.0 (https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html). What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using it as a library. It works in the GUI

Comment: And what version are you using?